# Encode URL and place it in javascript src

Tags: javascript

Need to encode following URL and place it in src="URL" to run the script with encoded URL. Is it possible?

```
<script>
var uri = "http://www.example.com";
var res = encodeURI(uri);
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='res'></script>
```

Comment: Use script to create a new script tag and insert it?

Comment: What is the point of doing that?

Comment: Need to encode url and add it into <script>, so that url should not be able to track by the users

Comment: Wait - you mean you need to hide the source url for the JS file from the user?

Comment: yes John, correct..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to dynamically generate a script tag and then insert it back into the document -- this will load your script:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://www.example.com";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

There are other techniques using AMD/Require, but this will work in a pinch.

You shouldn't need to encode it unless you're accepting the URL as user input directly, you could use `encodeURIComponent(str)` which is well documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), but utlimately if you're accepting user input here they could point to any arbitrary nefarious script source...